# char* ptr to struct

Tags: c

I've come across some C code that I don't quite understand. The following compiles and runs just fine. 1) Why can I cast a char* to a struct* and 2) is there any advantage to using this idiom instead of a void* ?

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char *nextPtr;
};

. . .

// This seems wrong
char *charPtr = NULL;

// Why not
//void *structPtr = NULL;

struct foo *fooPtr;
fooPtr = (struct foo*)charPtr;
```

// Edit removing the string portion as that's not really the point of the question.

Comment: What is `string`? Is this C or C++?

Comment: You can cast anything to anything with C style cast syntax. The compiler just trusts you. There was a time before the invention of `void*` that `char*` was used instead, but that time has long since passed.

Comment: Sorry, c++ if that's relevant.

Comment: I don't see how your code runs, you write to fooPtr->a, but fooPtr is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can convert between pointer types because this is the flexibility the language gives you. However, you should be cautious and know what you are doing or problems are likely.
2. No. There is an advantage to using the property pointer type so that no conversion is needed. If that isn't possible, it doesn't really matter if you use void*, although it may be slightly more clear to developers reading your code.

Comment: using char * meant for debugging purposes to print the struct's elements in one sentence like `printf("*fooPtr contains %s\n", charPtr)`

Comment: @AhmedJolani: That seems like a horrible design. structures can contain data that converts to non-printable characters, and may or may not be properly terminated.

Comment: according to his case no, two integers will never have a NULL value \x00, if *nextPtr is NULL then the printf would describe the values perfectly, and an integer always have a printable character (digits).

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that integers will never contain 0, but even so, what if the structure needed to be changed in the future?

Comment: it will and the ASCII code for the 0 is 0x30 not 0x00 (NULL POINTER) which will never terminate the string reading process.

Comment: @AhmedJolani: Huh? I said I'm not sure that the integers will never contain '0', I said 0.

Comment: ok well for the 0 without quotes the ASCII is still 0x30 it's a digit, that's how it's saved in memory, that's why computers uses ASCII unless you mean assigning a null to an integer and it will still be a 0.

Comment: No, 0 without the quotes is zero. And that's the null terminator. Why is this so difficult? How can you assure the structure will always contain exactly one zero value at the end of the structure? How can you assure the structure contains only printable characters? What happens if the structure definition changes?

Comment: Ok that's correct but '0' is NOT a null pointer '\0' is, you can't assign a '\0' to an integer, but if the integer is left uninitialized then all of what you said will be correct and debugging like that would be a horrible idea, in average cases the designer of this code maybe wanted to print the structure as one string, I am just analyzing the code no more.

Comment: If you set an integer to, say, 123, the integer *will* will contain zero (0x00, '\0', zero, null-terminator, whatever the heck you want to call a zero), because the most-significant bytes of the integer will be zero.

Comment: So what the heck is your point? If the value contains a 0 byte, then not all bytes of the structure will be printed. And if the value does not contain a zero byte, it will read past the end of the structure. Either way, how could you take exception to the statement that this is a very bad idea?

Comment: I am really sorry I don't know what I was thinking, we could get away with it by reading byte-by-byte anyway it's a bad design, sorry my experience is sill not that much I am still a university 3th year student joined stackoverflow to learn more. Sorry again.

Comment: @Ahmed Jolani, dug into the (legacy) code a little bit more and they do indeed print the struct in this way. They also use it as a poor man's linked list. Interesting...

Answer (score 1):

1) As mentioned, you can cast to any pointer type in C. (C++ may have more complex rules, the details of which I'm not aware)...

2) The benefit of `char*` vs `void*` is that you may perform pointer arithmetic on a `char*` but not on a `void*`.

The wisdom in performing pointer arithmetic is probably questionable based on the code you've posted, but it's often handy with structures which have variable length 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just coming across one of those classic "double-edged swords" of C.

In reality, a pointer is a pointer - just a variable that holds an address. You could, in theory, try to force that pointer to point to anything; a struct, an int, a (fill in the blank). C won't complain when you try to cast a pointer to one thing to a pointer for something else; it figures you know what you're doing. Heaven help you if you don't :)

In reality, yeah, a void * is probably a more apt way to declare a pointer that could point to next to anything, but I'm not sure it makes much difference in operation. Won't swear to that point, as there might be compiler optimizations and such that can take place if the pointer is strongly typed...